# Why the led isn't glowing?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics

Why doesn't the led glow?
[image: Bread Board Circuit]

I am trying to glow my LED For Making Project Of Detectore but it doesn't glow.

When i connect this circuit with my full project that time LED Wasn't Glowing After I Disconnected From Main Circuit and Make A Small Circuit For Testing Detector Circuit!!

I Do Small Circuit As Is Shown In Image.

I am using these components and my circuit connection as per image:

LM358

10k resistor

9V battery.

Comment: Explain why you *think* it *should* glow?   What voltage are you applying to the inputs?  Is this within the chip's `input common mode voltage range`?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Input is 9v bettery!!

Comment: That's the *supply*.  Question was about the *inputs*.  I can see what you did, but I want you to think about it, and think about if what you are doing is reasonable.  And even if it were reasonable (which it isn't) why do you think doing that would cause the LED to light?  If it does, it's only because you're leveraging ways in which a simple model breaks down in practice.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The LM358 is a low power dual operational amplifier integrated circuit originally introduced by National Semiconductor. It is used in detector circuits.

Comment: Which says nothing about why you expect this out-of-bounds circuit to light your LED.  What, in your own thinking, do you imagine is the **theory of operation** that would lead the LED to light?

Comment: @ChrisStratton if i use this out - bound circuit in any project which made by detector that time i need this circuit!!  But first i need to complete my out-bound circuit gentleman!!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Or one more thing that are you here only for give down vote to all questions???  If you are not able to give answer than pass the question why are you go for down vote!!

Comment: @Nemish Actually Chris is helping to improve the quality of questions and answers, and probably didn't downvote you, so please chill a bit.

Comment: @Nemish, please don't be rude to those trying to help you. You have no schematic in your question so it is difficult to see what you are trying to make and how you expect it to work. That makes your question a poor one. I suggest you read each comment carefully and edit your question to clarify each point raised.

Comment: Please post a schematic next time instead of (only) making a picture of the breadboard.

Comment: @Nemish The point of Stack Exchange is to collect good answers to good questions. This is not a forum. Bad questions must be removed to keep the quality.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ok

Comment: @Transistor okk

Answer (score 1):

The LED **should** go on, at least for a while, if this is connected sensibly. I have the following comments:

1. There is a schematic creator button, please use that to communicate circuits, though the photo is useful in this case too.
2. You should have series resistor for the LED. The short-circuit output current of the op-amp is enough to possibly damage an LED, but it probably won't happen instantly.
3. You appear to be trying to stuff stranded wire into a solderless breadboard. Maybe one or more connections are not being made.
4. The LED may be backwards (usually the long pin would be towards pin 1 of the dual op-amp), or perhaps your battery is dead.
5. There are some other comments about common mode range of the inputs, however the LM358 will give a proper output if at least one input is within the common-mode range (which is between about 0V and supply voltage minus 2 or 3V). When it is working normally we would expect BOTH inputs to be within that range.

Edit: As per @ChrisStratton, if BOTH inputs are outside the common mode range, then the output will be low and the LED will not light. That *is* what you have. So you need to bring at least one input within the common mode range.

---

Edit: Consider the schematic of one of the amplifiers of the LM358:

[image]

In your case you have the (+) input tied to V+ through a 10K resistor, so Q3 and Q4 will be "off" and all the 6uA bias current will flow through Q8, meaning the collector of Q9 is almost at ground potential, Q10 drags the base of Q11 down, turning off Q12, the collector is pulled up by the 100uA source and the output rails high.

However if BOTH inputs are close to the V+ supply, the 6uA current source will no longer work and the output will go low. That is your current situation.

Comment: LM358 can't source enough current to damage a LED, in the photo that resistor is in the +ve rail,

Comment: If you expect this to work with the non-inverting input tied to the + supply and the inverting input tied the + supply through a 10k resistor, the explanation of what implementation details in this particular type of op-amp cause that would make interesting reading.  Voltage drop in the resistor from input current?

Comment: @Jasen Actually the datasheet says **40mA** can be considered the maximum source current, which will damage many 5mm LEDs if left on continuously. See [note 6, page 6](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Okay, I'll add that, though I think it's pretty obvious from the schematic.

Comment: short circuit current: yeah i sit corrected.

Comment: Just measured one- from a 9V supply with red LED in series 41mA.

Comment: So does your LED light if you duplicate this circuit, with *both* inputs connected to the 9v supply, inverting one via a 10K resistor?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ah, crap I thought he had the (-) input grounded. You're right. As I said, at least ONE input must be within the common mode range. Answer corrected, thanks!

Comment: I suspect the issue is simpler than that. Let's ignore CMV issues, output current limits, and all that. The + input is tied low, and the - input is tied high. So the output SHOULD be low, and the LED SHOULD be off.

Answer (score 0):

LM358 cannot work correctly such a high voltage on the inputs - input voltage must be at-least 2V lower than supply positive.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf
table 7.3 "V<sub>CM</sub>"

Also note that the inputs to this amplifier are current sources, so were the voltages in range (eg connect the inputs to ground instead) the one with the 10K resistor would see a higher voltage than the other.

Also as Spehro Pefhany notes, a resistor should be used to limit the current into the LED 1K would be good.